# How to extend knockout observables with Decorators using Typescript?

Tags: typescript

How to extend knockout observables with Decorators using Typescript?
Example: Use Decorators for Validation.

```
interface Person {
    firstname:string;
}

class PersonViewModel {
    @required
    firstname = ko.observable<string>();
    constructor (person:Person) {
        // put this in an required decorators
        // this.firstname.extend({required:true})
        this.firstname(person.firstname);
    }
}

function required(target, key) {
    // ????
    // pseudo code extend Person Class variable firstname
    // ???firstname.extend({required:true})
}
```

Comment: I might be mistaken (haven't used decorators yet), but isn't this as simple as calling `target[key].extend({required:true})` ?